# Jquery Ajax send Request to Laravel put Route but formData is empty

Tags: jquery, ajax, laravel, form-data

in my `home.blade.php`, i have a component receives `users` from some controller and then loops over `users` and show the data, the component has `bootstrap modal`, when button `edit` is clicked, `modal` will open and by writing some mix of `jquery` and `javascript`, when `edit` is clicked, it sends the old input values to edit, anyway, when the user is done editing and button `confirm` is clicked, the `Jquery Ajax` script will send request to some controller with the user data to update, but it shows me server error that i'm doing `update()` method on `null`, so after reviewing my code, i found out that the `formData` is actually empty, so it sends an a request with empty `data` and then the controller is doing `update()` for the `user` but there are nothing to update, so i don't know why could these lines of code `const form = $('#editForm')[0]; const formData = new FormData(form);` are not working ?

```blade
@extends('layouts.app')

@section('content')

<table class="table" id="table" >

 @foreach($users as $user)

    <tr>
        <th>Student Name</th>
        <th>Email</th>
        <th>Active</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>{{$user->username}}</td>
        <td>{{$user->email}}</td>
        <td>{{$user->active ? 'Active' : 'Inactive'}}</td>
        <td style="width: 40px"><button 
        data-username="{{$user->username}}" 
        data-email="{{$user->email}}" 
        data-active="{{$user->active}}" 
        data-id="{{$user->id}}" 
        type="button" 
        class="btn btn-primary edit" 
        data-bs-toggle="modal" 
        data-bs-target="#exampleModal">Edit</button></td>
        <td style="width: 40px"><button type="button" class="btn btn-danger">Delete</button></td>
        <td style="width: 40px"><button type="button" class="btn btn-warning">{{$user->active ? 'Activate' : 'Deactivate'}}</button></td>

    </tr>
    @endforeach


</table>
<div class="modal fade" id="exampleModal" tabindex="-1" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog" style="margin-top: 200px">
    <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
        <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">Modal title</h5>
        <button type="button" class="btn-close" data-bs-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"></button>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
            <form id="editForm">
                    <input id="username" type="text" name="username"
                    class="form-control"
                    >
                    <label for="email" class="form-label">email</label>
                    <input id="email" type="text" name="email"
                    class="form-control"
                    >
                    <input type="hidden" id="id" name="id">
                    <div class="mt-4">
                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary me-2" data-bs-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                        <button id="activateStatus" type="button" class=" btn btn-primary me-2"></button>
                        <button id="button" class="btn btn-primary me-2">Confirm</button>
                    </div>


                </div>
        </form>
    </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

```js
const table = document.querySelector("#table");

table.addEventListener("click", (e) => {
  if (e.target.classList.contains("edit")) {
    $("#id").val(e.target.dataset.id);
    $("#username").val(e.target.dataset.username);
    $("#email").val(e.target.dataset.email);
    $("#activateStatus").text(
      Number(e.target.dataset.active) ? "Deactivate" : "Activate",
    );
  }
});

$(document).ready(function () {
  $.ajaxSetup({
    headers: {
      "X-CSRF-TOKEN": $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr("content"),
    },
  });

  $("#editForm").submit(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    const form = $("#editForm")[0];
    const formData = new FormData(form);
    $.ajax({
      type: "PUT",
      url: '{{route("edit")}}',
      data: formData,
      processData: false,
      contentType: false,
      success: function (response) {
        console.log(response);
      },
      error: function (errResponse) {
        console.log(errResponse);
      },
    });
  });
});
```

Comment: What version of Bootstrap are you using? From memory, some versions clone the modal content so you might be ending up with two `#editForm` elements

Comment: i solved the problem by using ```serializeArray()``` instead of ```formData```

Comment: That's odd. PHP typically handles `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` and `multipart/form-data` the same way.